# Firebase setValue crashes, "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently working on an app that is designed to submit data to a realtime Firebase database and I keep getting "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". Swift tells me that it's my function "post()" that's causing the crash, but I'm not able to find anything that would cause the crash in that function.

Post function that is responsible for the crash:

```
    func post() {
    var post = [String: String]()
    post = ["agent": (Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName)!,
            "destination": destinationField.text!,
            "date": dateField.text!,
            "guests": guestsField.text!,
            "hotel": hotelField.text!,
            "name": fullNameField.text!,
            "price": getFinalPrice(),
            "room": roomField.text!,
            "submitted": getCurrentTime(),
            "time": timeField.text!]

    print(post)
    ref.child("Orders").childByAutoId().setValue(post)
}
```

Here's what the "print" line in that function returns:

```
["name": "Andrei Georgescu", "destination": "SFO", "room": "493", "guests": "2", "agent": "Doxify", "date": "Jan 6, 2018", "submitted": "Jan 6, 2018 at 1:17 AM", "hotel": "Whitcomb", "price": "344", "time": "1:17 AM"]
```

I should also note that Xcode tells me that it crashes on the "setValue" line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Further troubleshooting is needed. As is, the post object's key: value pairs are all populated correctly (as shown by the print statement) so it's possible *ref* is not valid (not likely, but to test, add print(ref) before that line). Also, if one of the post's values was nil, it would crash on that line instead of on the setValue line. In general though - force unwrapping those values is probably not a good idea. There's a reason they could be nil so to protect your code you should handle them in that fashion; possibly setting a default using Nil Coalescing; let date = dateField.text ?? ""

Comment: It was the ref, for some reason I deleted it from my viewDidLoad and forgot to add it back, thanks!